# Linked data cannot export armatures/animations on fbx files

Tags: armature, export, linked-data, .fbx

Working on a huge project, i have to use multiple meshes and collections and i have them all in separated blender files, i want to use linked collections to assemble all the objects and export this new locations without messing with armature constraits and animations.

So i finish this new blender file with linked collections (for everything to come toghether) and export in fbx.

When importing the final scene to 3rd party program or even other blender file (fbx) there is no armature, this means no bones and no animation at all, i can see the mesh and materials.

Seems like exporting fbx from linked data does not support armatures/animations.

Am i doing something wrong with linked data? or is this a bug or a feature?.

**Steps to reproduce this:**

Create blender file, create armature and simple animation.

Create second blender file and link the first blender file object's data (including armature and animation of course).

Export an fbx of the test mesh/armature from this second blender file.

Import in a new blender file the fbx. (there should be no armature/animation).

**Working on blender 2.93.1**

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just got into blender manual, seems like armature instances are not supported for fbx export.

If anyone wants to know more go here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html